# How do I detect if a candle closes above/below a pivot point?

Tags: pine-script

I'm new to Pine script and want to code a simple indicator that detects if a candle closes above a pivot high or below a pivot low.

I successfully implemented the pivot points and label them correctly.

The problem is that checking if the close of a candle is higher/lower than the pivot high/low does not work. The labels at the candle breaking out of a pivot point don't show up even though they should.

I'm using a simple if statement to check if the close is higher / lower.

Here is my code:

```
//@version=4
study("Test", overlay=true)


// Pivot points implementation

leftbars = input(7)
rightbars = input(7)

phigh = pivothigh(high, leftbars, rightbars)
plow = pivotlow (low , leftbars, rightbars)


// Printing a label at pivot points 

label1 = phigh ? label.new(bar_index[rightbars], high[rightbars], text=tostring(phigh), style=label.style_labeldown, color=color.white) : na
label2 = plow ? label.new(bar_index[rightbars], low[rightbars], text=tostring(plow), style=label.style_labelup, color=color.white) : na


// Checking if close is higher than the pivot high or lower than the pivot low

if (close > phigh)
    label.new(bar_index, close, text="Breakout Candle Pivot High")


if (close < plow)
    label.new(bar_index, close, text="Breakout Candle Pivot Low")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed,

https://www.tradingview.com/x/7q60SFDV/

```
//@version=4
study("Test", overlay=true)



// Pivot points implementation

leftbars = input(7, "leftbars")
rightbars = input(7, "right")


phigh = pivothigh(high, leftbars, rightbars)
plow = pivotlow (low , leftbars, rightbars)


// Use valuewhen to store value of pivot point

Storedphigh = valuewhen(phigh, phigh, 0)
plot(Storedphigh, title="Phigh", offset=-leftbars)


Storedplow = valuewhen(plow, plow, 0)
plot(Storedplow, title="Plow", offset=-leftbars)


// Printing a label at pivot points 

label1 = phigh ? label.new(bar_index[rightbars], high[rightbars], text=tostring(phigh), style=label.style_labeldown, color=color.white) : na
label2 = plow ? label.new(bar_index[rightbars], low[rightbars], text=tostring(plow), style=label.style_labelup, color=color.white) : na


//Checking if close is higher than the pivot high or lower than the pivot low
//
if (crossover(close, Storedphigh))
    label.new(bar_index, high, text="Breakout Candle Pivot High", style=label.style_label_down)


if (crossunder(close, Storedplow))
    label.new(bar_index, low, text="Breakout Candle Pivot High", style=label.style_label_up)
```

Comment: Thanks, but the labels that are showing are just the pivot points. What I meant was that the crossover and crossunder labels don't work. There should be these "Breakout Candle Pivot High" labels showing crossovers. but they don't show up. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Sry, I misread it. Your code were missing storing value of pivots. Labels are working now.
better plot everything to debug it, if you look at data window, you can see phigh and plow were na most of the time hence storing a value was required.

Please Press add reputation if this helped you.